# transmit 16 bit number instead of 8

Tags: c, microcontroller

Prob a long shot but I am trying to transmit a 16 bit number via C and the TI MSP430 to a python script.

I have no problem transmitting 8 bit numbers, up to 255 that is, but once the number goes over 255 it becomes Whatever number that is minus 256. For example if I try to transmit the number 300 I get 44 instead.

I am really not sure what part of the code I should change as it is not my code and I am new to all this. i am trying to modify existing code. Here are the relevant bits I think : Here is the code, can someone help me modify the code to transmit numbers higher than 236. Probably up to like 2000 or so. THANKS!

```
unsigned char BitCnt;
unsigned int TXByte;

void Transmit(void);

void main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD; // Stop WDT


        TXByte = 300;
        Transmit();

    }

}

void Transmit()
{

  BitCnt = 0xA;           // Load Bit counter, 8 data + Start/Stop bit
  TXByte |= 0x100;        // Add mark stop bit to TXByte
  TXByte = TXByte << 1;   // Add space start bit


  TACCR0 = TAR+ Bitime;
  TACCTL0 =  CCIS0 + OUTMOD0 + CCIE;   // TXD = mark = idle, enable interrupts
  // OUTMOD0 sets output mode 1: SET which will
  // have the CCR bit (our TX bit) to go high when the timer expires
  while ( TACCTL0 & CCIE );                   // Wait for TX completion
}
```

Python script: 
So now I need to edit my python script to combine these two sets of 8-bit numbers. Currently I have something like:

```
while(1): #loop forever
    data = ser.read(1) # look for a character from serial port
    if len(data) > 0: #was there a byte to read? Will always be true
        yvals[49] = ord(data)
```

How would I combine the 8-bit sets of number? 'data' is the incoming information from the MSP430 controller.

Comment: Or do I have to modify the python script instead?

Answer (score 2):

Transmit your 16-bit number as two 8-bit ones :

```
TXByte = 300 >> 8;
Transmit();
TXByte = 300 & 0xff;
Transmit();
```

Of course, the receiving end has to know you're working with big-endian 16-bit words, otherwise you'll get false results.

Python's receiver :

```
while(1): #loop forever
    new_value = 0

    for byte_count in range(2): # we need to wait two bytes
        data = ser.read(1) # read one byte at a time
        if len(data) > 0: 
             # the first byte is right-shifted by b bits, the second not.
             new_value += ord(data[0]) << 8*(1-byte_count) 

    # new_values contains a 16-bit integer        
    yvals[49] = new_value
```

Comment: I added a piece of the python script that takes in the data. Any ideas how I can set it up to receive the new 2 8-bit numbers and combine them into a glorious 16-bit number?

Comment: Isn't there a way to just transmit the data in it's full 16-bit form by modifying the transmit function? Can I avoid splitting up the data into two 8-bit pieces?

Comment: Also, making the modifications you suggest doesn't exactly work. The data I get now switches between two integers: 120.0 and 30720.0 now when I try to transmit the number 300. Any thoughts to why that is?

Comment: I've forgot a '+' sign in the new_value. Now it shouldn't switch anymore. As for the two values, it means that data[0] == 'x', which means you are sending only x char. Why ? I don't know. You should check using a rs323 sniffer or wireshark if it's IP based.

Comment: Ya now it switches between 30720 and 30840. I dont think it is IP based or whatnot, because I could transmit the value 200 no problem or anything less than 256. With the code you suggested I don't get values below 256 now, just displays zero. And above 256 I only get the swtiching between 30720 ,30840. Sorry to keep bugging you - any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the following comment
//Load Bit counter, 8 data + Start/Stop bit.

If there are 8 data bits, the biggest number you can express is 2^8-1 = 255 
When you set the byte to 300 for example this is what happens:
300:        0b'100101100
empty byte:  0b'00000000
if you set the byte to 300, only the 8 least significant bits get copied (for the others is no space), so you end up with the number 0b'00101100 which is 44

EDIT:
imho you should change the transmit function such that it doesnt transmit a byte which is stored in a global but a byte which is input to the function, so you get: void transmit(unsigned char transmitByte)

Now you can build a new function:

```
void transmitBigNumber(unsigned short transmitBits) {
    transmit(transmitBits & 0x00FF); transmit(transmitBits >> 8);
}
```

On the receive side you do the same but the other way around and you merge the bytes again.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say the ability to transmit/receive 8-bits of data is the lowest level of communication and view this from the receiving end.  Certainly receiving all of the 65,536 combinations of 16-bits of data needs at least two 8-bit bytes.  But upon receiving a byte, is it the 1st or 2nd byte that was received?  Thus some *synchronization* is needed.  There are many standards ones can use.  I'll put forth an idea: variation on [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

When value is `0` to `127`, receiver sees `0-127` and knows the value.

When the value is `128-255`, receiver knows it is part of a multi-byte transfer.

All continuation bytes begin with `0b10xxxxxx`, so if one is first received, code discards that, waiting for a `0` to `127` or `0xb11xxxxxx`.

Upon receiving `0b110xxxxx`, code knows this is the beginning of a 2 byte sequence for the values `0x80` to `0x7FF`.

Upon receiving `0b1110xxxx`, code knows this is the beginning of a 3 byte sequence for the values `0x800` to `0xFFFF`.

16-bit values are formed from combining the optional `x` bits in the lead sequence and the continuation bytes per the UTF-8 spec.  [Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Examples)

Comment: so I need some more if statements in my C code or in my python script? Really confused how to implement what you suggested into my code